# In @user.name, how does ActiveRecord determines whether name is a database column or a method of the class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In @user.name, how does ActiveRecord determines whether name

is a database column or a method of the class ?

Comment: Thats the `active-record` by-default feature to make all the column names of the database as an instance method of the model.

Answer (score 0):

In short active-record will define the getter and setter method for each of the table column in the model class.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your tables with migrations, Rails will automatically assign whatever the name of the attribute/column as the name of the method for the Model:

```
create_table :users do |t|
    t.string "name" # name will be converted to a method for the Model User
 end
```

In the case you described, the database column name IS the method that is available for use. `@user.name` will search for the database column, and depending on what you set up `@user` to be, will check the name column on your database for a value. If there is a value, it will return to you that value. If there is no value, it will return nil.

Answer (score -1):

If User table have both column name and method name then it will call method name.

For eg.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def name
    "test"
  end
end
```

User table -> name column has one entry "Mohan"

```
User.first.name
"test" #because each column name in user table is getter setter method of ActiveRecord
```